# Bullet Physic: Stack transformations on body after adding

Tags: transformation, bullet-physics, rigid-body-dynamics

How can I stack multiple transformations on a body?
I mean... Rotate, translate and then rotate again?

If I understood, a transformation on a rigid body can be made like this:

```
    btTransform transform;

    transform.setOrigin( ... );
    transform.setRotation( ... );
    someRigidBody->setWorldTransform(transform);
```

But, this way I am forced to calculate the final rotation ( when is more natural stack the operations. So it can rotate on its own axis, translate and then rotate on a new axis )

Thank you

Comment: You can multiply transformations.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment to your question, btTransform is a matrix. You can do the matrix operations as you see fit, without using the set* methods.

Once you're satisfied, just use the matrix as you're doing now.